# How to have the frame of a scroll view change as you scroll in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to setup an interface like this with a content view on top and a scroll view at the bottom. When you scroll up in scroll view, I want the scroll view's frame to move up until it's fullscreen. Similarly, once the scroll view is fullscreen I want it to come back down when you scroll in the reverse direction. This is similar to the modal sheet behavior with detents, but I want both views to be interactive at the same time. Is this possible?

Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let content = 1...20
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Content View")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color(uiColor: .systemGray5))
            
            List {
                ForEach(content, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I want the frame to change as you scroll up.

[image]

Comment: Everything would have to be custom

Comment: Sure, but how do I track the position of the scroll view to change it's frame?

Comment: There are a few different ways out there, if you search for how to get the position of a `ScrollView` most use `PreferenceKey` and `GeometryReader`

Comment: The problem is I'm using a list which doesn't seem to support the same things as ScrollView.

Comment: It wouldn't, you should have to write everything custom

Comment: Ok, these seems like something better to do in UIKit with a representable view.